# delete line backwards (Emacs)

Tags: emacs

This is probably basic but I really tried to find the answer. "C-k" deletes from the cursor to the end of the line, but is there an analogous shortcut to delete a line backwards from the cursor point?
Best

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try `C-u 0 C-k` - i.e. C-k with the prefix 0 kills from point to the start of the line. See the documentation for C-k (kill-line) for more information.

Comment: Cant get C-0 C-k to work on my OS X emacs; just prints 0 and kills rest of line.

Comment: @The Unfun Cat: odd, it works for me (GNU Emacs 24 on Linux). I haven't got a Mac around, so I can't check if I can replicate the problem.

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin), that is probably the reason.

Comment: alt-0 C-k works also on commandline emacs style ! very useful

Comment: as of April '17 on OS X 10.11, `C-0 C-k` works in minibuffer but just `C-u` does the trick in bash console

Comment: On the command line alt-<minus> works for me to kill backwards, and alt-0 does not. Not sure why.

Answer (score 10):

As other answers suggest, <kbd>C-0</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> kills from point to the start of the line. See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html) for <kbd>C-k</kbd> ([`kill-line`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html)) for more information. You may also want to kill the whole line before and after point with <kbd>C-S-backspace</kbd> which evals `kill-whole-line`.

Another convenience for killing is to rebind `kill-region` which defaults to <kbd>C-w</kbd> and instead bind to that key the function `backward-kill-word` which will then mimic the behavior of [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC17)'s <kbd>C-w</kbd> ([`unix-word-rubout`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC17)). I rebind `kill-region` to <kbd>C-q</kbd> after moving `quoted-insert` to <kbd>A-q</kbd>. Yes, this requires moving a number of keys around, but if you give it a try I think you'll find it is convenient.

Comment: Works also fine in Minibuffer.

Answer (score 7):

Here's asjo's answer bound to a key:

```
(global-set-key "\M-k" '(lambda () (interactive) (kill-line 0)) ) ;M-k kills to the left
```

Comment: I've made the same shortcut myself, it's extremly handy in the long run. I've also found that `M-m M-k` is even more handy in the long run :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried <kbd>C-u</kbd> with a negative number and <kbd>C-k</kbd> as arguments. It worked.

Example to delete 4 lines before cursor, try <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>-4</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd>

Comment: very interesting, never thought of this, but I was intending to find a simple way of the deletion on the current line with the cursor at the end, but this can take the cursor to the start of various lines behind it, which generalizes things which is great

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly to the beginning of a line, but you might want to check out the [`hungry-delete`](https://melpa.org/#/hungry-delete) package. Install, then add the following to the init file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda ()
  (require 'hungry-delete)
  (global-hungry-delete-mode)))
```

After that <kbd>DEL</kbd> would delete up to the next non-whitespace character, and so would <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> (because <kbd>C-0</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> doesn't work on my computer).

To delete all blank spaces in the beginning of a line:

<kbd>M-m</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd>.